# Spark job running out of heap memory on takeSample

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cloud

I've got an Apache spark cluster with one master node and three worker nodes. The worker nodes have 32 cores and 124G of memory each.  I've also got a dataset in HDFS with around 650 million text records.  This dataset is a number of serialized RDDs read in like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, SparseVector}
val vectors = sc.objectFile[(String, SparseVector)]("hdfs://mn:8020/data/*")
```

I'd like to extract a sample of one million of these records to do some analytics, so I figured I'd try `val sample = vectors.takeSample(false, 10000, 0)`.  However, that eventually fails with this error message:

```
 15/08/25 09:48:27 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-3
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResult.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1239)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.readExternal(TaskResult.scala:61)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult$$anonfun$readExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResult.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1239)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.readExternal(TaskResult.scala:61)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1837)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$r
```

I understand that I'm running out of heap space (on the driver, I think?), and that makes sense.  Doing `hadoop fs -du -s /path/to/data`, the dataset takes up 2575 Gigabytes on disk (but is only ~850 GB in size).

So, my question is, what can I do to extract this sample of 1000000 records (which I later plan on serializing to disk)?  I know I could just do `takeSample()` with smaller sample sizes and aggregate them later, but I think I'm just not setting the correct configuration or doing something wrong, which is preventing me from doing this the way I'd like.

Comment: I ended up having to increase `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to get things working.  Also, tuning my cluster per the accepted response probably helped as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do so by increasing the number of partitions, making each one smaller. It would also be important to check the number of executors you are setting up and how much memory is reserved for each one (you did not put this info on the question).

I have found [this guide](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) to be very useful for tuning Spark.

Comment: I typically did not set `--num-executors` in the past, and would set `--executor-memory 124G` and `--executor-cores 32`.  If I set `--num-executors` to a number greater than 3, will that mean that I just have more than one executor running per node?  Will this require me to proportionally reduce the settings I have in `--executor-cores` and `--executor-memory`?

Comment: Correct! Depending on your cluster configuration, you might also need some space for the master program. It is highly variable, but I usually divide capacity in thirds or quarters. Say, you could go with 9 total executors, 10 cores and 40 GB each, leaving something for the OS, etc.

Comment: Also, note that your memory issue can well be on the driver. There is also configuration for `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.driver.cores`, `spark.driver.maxResultSize`, etc.

Comment: To clarify--the spark web UI doesn't reflect these per-executor stats, correct?  To me, it seems like it only displays stats (such as cores and memory used) per physical worker node.

Comment: It does, be sure to look at all tabs! There is a list of executors with a lot of information.

Answer (score 4):

When working with big data it is seldom a good idea to collect the intermediate results at the driver node. Instead it is almost always better to keep the data distributed in your cluster. The same holds true for the sample you want to take.

If you want to sample 1000000 elements of your data set to write it to disk afterwards, then why not taking the sample and writing it to disk without collecting it at the driver? The following code snippet should do exactly this

```scala
val sample = vectors.zipWithIndex().filter(_._1 < 1000000).map(_._2)

sample.saveAsObjectFile("path to file")
```

Comment: Will this only take the first 1000000 records? I was hoping for a randomly distributed sample

Comment: @NathanielPawelczyk, depending on the preceding Spark operations the results might be random. The JavaDocs of `zipWithIndex` say: "Note that some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not guarantee order of elements in a partition. The index assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed, and may even change if the RDD is reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee the same index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it to a file."

Comment: But if your sample does not have to be of fixed size, then you can also use the `RDD.sample(false, p, 0)` operation which creates a sample which is the `p`-th fraction of the original RDD.